# Interactive substitution - re.sub() with pos?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I would like to search and replace using regular expressions, let's say I want to have *some* digits followed by 'm '.

```py
import re
pattern = '(\d)'
repl = r'\1 m'
line = 'Each of the 2 cars is 5 long.'
```

Since a simple

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, line)
```

cannot give the desired result, I would like to this **interactively**, i.e. the user has to confirm each substitution, the corresponding part of the string and several characters around it is displayed. This can easily be done using `match.start()` etc.

Using `re.compile()`, we get methods like `search()` etc. with the useful parameter `pos`, but for `sub()` this does not exist. Examples:

```
regex = re.compile(pattern)
regex.match(line, pos=15)
regex.sub(repl, line, count=1)
```

It is possible to loop over `line` using `regex.finditer()` (with `pos` taken from the end of the previous match) and then substitute, *but how can this be done correctly and elegantly?* The matches itself do not provide a method `sub`.

It is required to use `repl` for the substitution.

Note that the length of `line` changes. Also note that splitting the string `line` would change the meaning of `'^'` in regular expressions, which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a function as the replacement, and have that function do the prompting.  See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) for how substitution functions work.  Here is a simple example:

```
def confirmSub(match):
    print("Going to replace", match.string[match.start()-5:match.end()+5])
    x = raw_input("OK?")
    if x.lower().startswith("y"):
        return match.group() + "m"
    return match.group()
```

Here is how it works on your example:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\d', confirmSub, "Each of the 2 cars is 5 long.")
Going to replace  the 2 cars
OK?n
Going to replace s is 5 long
OK?y
'Each of the 2 cars is 5m long.'
```

If you want to be able to pass your replacement pattern in, you can elaborate on this by making `confirmSub` a function that takes the replacement pattern and returns a replacing function that uses that pattern:

```
def confirmSub(replacement):
    def confirmer(match):
        print("Going to replace", match.string[match.start()-5:match.end()+5])
        x = raw_input("OK?")
        if x.lower().startswith("y"):
            return re.sub(match.re.pattern, replacement, match.group())
        return match.group()
    return confirmer
```

Then:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(\d)', confirmSub(r"\1m"), "Each of the 2 cars is 5 long.")
Going to replace  the 2 cars
OK?n
Going to replace s is 5 long
OK?y
'Each of the 2 cars is 5m long.'
```

There may be edge cases where this won't work (e.g., if the matching regex uses lookarounds).

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. This is an unexpected use of the function. Is there a way to use `repl`? I need this as a regular expression, not hard-coded.

Comment: Thanks again! This might indeed solve most cases. The answer is acceptable, but let's wait a few days for an alternative solution.